# CSS Rounded borders on tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to get rounded corners on tables with various child elements as in this bin: http://jsbin.com/seqisa/1/

I can get the shaded background to have rounded corners, but nothing I do seems to affect the border line.  I have read several other questions that seem to ask the smae thing, but none of the answers provided seem to work for me.

This is what I'm getting at the moment.  The `caption` element behaves fine, but none of the `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot` work. I have tried setting the `border` on every element individually , but none of them result in rounded corners.

[image: Current output]

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>
    <caption>Caption</caption>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table>
    <caption>Caption</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Footer 1</th>
        <td>Footer 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* Basic styling */
table {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
caption { background-color: green; }
thead { background-color: blue; }
tbody { background-color: lightgray; }
tfoot { background-color: magenta; }
th, td, caption { padding: 4px; }

/* Radius */
table > :first-child,
table > :first-child > tr:first-child > td:first-child,
table > :first-child > tr:first-child > th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

table > :first-child,
table > :first-child > tr:first-child > td:last-child,
table > :first-child > tr:first-child > th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

table > :last-child,
table > :last-child > tr:last-child > td:first-child,
table > :last-child > tr:last-child > th:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

table > :last-child,
table > :last-child > tr:last-child > td:last-child,
table > :last-child > tr:last-child > th:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

/* Borders */

table > * {
  border: 2px solid darkred;
}
```

Comment: try to add the border and border-radius to thead and tfoot or tbody if tfoot not exists only

Comment: I tried that already, doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this **CSS**

```
* { border-collapse: separate; }
```

`border-radius` won't work with `border-collapse: collapse;` due to *W3C.org* specifications.

Comment: But `border-collapse: separate` puts big gaps between each cell, so how would I prevent that then?

Comment: u can use `border-spacing:0px` to prevent the gaps

Comment: Thank you @UnskilledFreak for this comment. I've been searching for ages for this trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try add below like CSS for your own purpose

```
   table {
     border-image: none;
     border:5px solid red;
     border-top:0 none;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
   }
```

the result i took, though i'm not sure if you really asked for below result..

[image]